# Big clunk/thunk when stopping fully

Tags: toyota, manual-transmission, truck, tacoma

This problem started about a month ago. Just got back from traveling for the holidays and have to resolve this problem ASAP. Sometimes, but not always, the truck will clunk or thud hard when going from almost stopped to a complete stop. Often it's just one thunk, but sometimes it almost feels like two distinct thunks. Check out this video (sound may be helpful).

This problem happens in neutral, first, or reverse. Clutch can be pressed in or let out (when in neutral). I'm noticing it when the stop is gradual, probably most often when going down a slight decline.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4B3vAvmQYQ

Truck: 2000 Toyota Tacoma 4x4 3.4L V6 manual transmission

Comment: How many miles? im thinking its a worn suspension bushing. I had a jetta that lost all the rubber in the a arm bushing and the wheel would visibly move 2-3 inches in the wheel well when you stopped. You possibly might be able to lift the vehicle and feel loose suspension components through the wheel but sometimes it takes alot more force than you can exert.          That clunk is so loud i think you might be able to have someone watch for it. If its not suspension my next guess would be either engine/tranny/diff mounts. Maybe driving over a camera thats recording might be able to help?

Comment: 171k. It has new upper and lower ball joints, front and rear springs and shocks and struts. New inner and outer tie rods. I think the suspension is fine.

Comment: hmmm if thats the case then im definitely leaning towards diff/ tranny/engine mount in that order. Its a very loud clunk so it should be visible what is hitting.Driving over a camera(Without crushing it!) a couple of times at different angles should be able to help. This is not a small part causing this noise(let me know if thats not your exact video). I have no clue how the sub frames are set up on these cars(Could be unibody) but thats also another big big bushing to keep an eye out for.

Comment: The transmission mount is very good, and I expect the engine mounts are too since the engine doesn’t move too much when I crank the car or give it revs. Also note this is at really low speed, so I’m not sure how those mounts could move that much at low speed. I can actually cause this to happen by reversing and going forward repeatedly at no more than 5 mph. I suspect something is binding in the driveline and then unloading.

Comment: yea the engine mounts would be last, if all mounts and suspension are good then the only thing i can think of is some back and forth tolerance has found its way in your drive train. The power of the engine holds everything tight but the second its stops pushing everything lets loose and clunks in a certain spot   
                                                                              
           https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GkdIAOYNZAk                                                 I think this might be your offender??